# Итерация элементов вложенных списков посредством индексов

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть при данной конструкции.
Есть некий список с вложенными списками. Вложенных списков может быть любое количество:

```
[[10,2,4,12], [1,2,56,10], [1,13,25,78]]
```

Каждый вложенный список должен сравнивать свои индексы 0 и 1 с индексами 0 и 1 других вложенных списков и вне зависимости от их местоположения внутри основного списка.
Если значения индекса 1 совпадает, а значение индекса 0 не совпадает, тогда добавить списки в новый список `all = []`

Есть лаконичные решения этого вопроса, кроме как использовать словари? Знаний написать грамотные костыли нет. Библиотека itertools не подойдет?

UPD Решений подобного характера ожидается много, поэтому если разжуете, буду очень признателен.

Comment: а что это у вас за тип данных в списках?

Comment: str, float. Других не бывает.

Comment: @Antony , Вам как бы намекают, что приведенный фрагмент не является корректным кодом на питоне.  Приведите хотя бы 3 строчки корректного кода...  Или это просто текстовые данные?

Comment: Простите, в запаре бред написал. Сейчас исправлю. Готово.

Comment: Действительно, можно использовать `itertools.combinations(a, 2)`. И попарно сравнивать (ну если список не слишком большой). Дальше просто надо уточнить задачу, если условиям удовлетворяют несколько элементов, в `all` все найденные пары надо поместить?   Т.е. не хватает желательного результата, хотя бы на этом микропримере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае подойдёт итератор `itertools.combinations` если вам нужно пробежаться по всем парам вложенных списков без учёта перестановки списков внутри пары, или `itertools.permutations` если учёт важен.

К примеру:

```py
import itertools

a = [[10,2,4,12], [1,2,56,10], [1,13,25,78]]

for element1, element2 in itertools.combinations(a, 2):
    print(element1,element2)
'''
[10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 2, 56, 10]
[10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 13, 25, 78]
[1, 2, 56, 10] [1, 13, 25, 78]
'''
```

Или:

```py
import itertools

a = [[10,2,4,12], [1,2,56,10], [1,13,25,78]]

for element1, element2 in itertools.permutations(a, 2):
    print(element1, element2)
'''
[10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 2, 56, 10]
[10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 13, 25, 78]
[1, 2, 56, 10] [10, 2, 4, 12]
[1, 2, 56, 10] [1, 13, 25, 78]
[1, 13, 25, 78] [10, 2, 4, 12]
[1, 13, 25, 78] [1, 2, 56, 10]
'''
```

Затем можно сравнить индексы 0 и 1 пар списков, и работать дальше. В вашем случае:

```py
import itertools

a = [[10,2,4,12], [1,2,56,10], [1,13,25,78]]

for element1, element2 in itertools.combinations(a, 2):
    tupleInd = list(zip(element1, element2))

    index0 = tupleInd[0] # Кортеж, содержащий первые элементы двух списков
    index1 = tupleInd[1] # Кортеж, содержащий вторые элементы двух списков

    if index0[0] != index0[1] and index1[0] == index1[1]:
        print(element1, element2) # [10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 2, 56, 10]
        
        #do stuff...
```

При заданном `a` проходит только пара списков `[10, 2, 4, 12] [1, 2, 56, 10]`, так как `10 != 1` и `2 == 2`.

Comment: Спасибо, я не до конца расписал задачу. Вложенных списков может быть любое количество. Оно рандомное.

Comment: Zip работает с любым количеством аргументов. Главное не забудьте раскрыть список посредством использования * перед именем списка.

Comment: ```if not same(zipa[0]) and same(zipa[1]):```. Я правильно понимаю, что zip просто обращается к содержимому внутренних списков?

Comment: Да, так и есть, иначе он бы просто не мог выполнить свою функцию. А в выделенной вами области я использовал не саму zip, а zipa - переменную, которую я объявил чуть ранее.

Comment: а как Вам такое? ```for name, number in zip(employee_names, employee_numbers):
 print(name, number)``` вместо функции?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду. Если смысл цикла `for` - перебрать все объекты и их индексы, то проще использовать `enumerate`. Прошу, опишите, что вы подразумеваете под "функцией" в данном случае.

Comment: Я не могу понять где здесь итератор. Я вижу, что вы используете индексы. А мне нужен итератор. Видимо, не догоняю пока.

Comment: Прошу меня простить, я изначально не так понял смысл данной задачи, из-за чего сделал не те выводы. Очень жаль, что потратил ваше время впустую. Ответ полностью перестроен, если что-то не будет работать - с радостью подкорректирую.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!